# How to partially parse JSON using Go?

Tags: json, go, struct

I have the following json:

```
{
    "app": {
        "name": "name-of-app",
        "version" 1
    },
    "items": [
        {
            "type": "type-of-item",
            "inputs": {
                "input1": "value1"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

The `items[0].inputs` change based on the `items[0].type`.

Knowing that, is there a way to keep the `inputs` field a string? The idea is to use the `type` to call the right handler passing the `inputs`, and in there I would parse the `inputs` string using the right struct.

Example:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "encoding/json"
)

type Configuration struct {
    App   App `json:"app"`
    Items []Item `json:"items"`
}

type App struct {
    Name    string `json:"name"`
    Version int    `json:"version"`
}

type Item struct {
    Type string `json:"type"`
    // What to put here to mantain the field a string so I can Unmarshal later?
    // Inputs string
}

var myJson = `
{
    "app": {
        "name": "name-of-app",
        "version": 1
    },
    "items": [
        {
            "type": "type-of-item",
            "inputs": {
                "input1": "value1"
            }
        }
    ]
}
`

func main() {
    data := Configuration{}
    json.Unmarshal([]byte(myJson), &data)

    fmt.Println("done!", data)
    // Loop through data.Items and use the type to define what to call, and pass inputs
    // as argument
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: See if it's clear now @BasileStarynkevitch

Comment: No, because JSON is designed to be *fully* parsed. Look again on http://json.org/ and show some [MCVE] *with Go code* (that we could run on *our* computer) in your question. Perhaps you are using "JSON parsing" in a way that is not the common meaning of it.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I added an example.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Use [json.RawMessage](https://godoc.org/encoding/json#RawMessage) to get the raw JSON text of the `inputs` field:

```
type Item struct {
    Type   string `json:"type"`
    Inputs json.RawMessage
}
```

Use it like this:

```
var data Configuration
if err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(myJson), &data); err != nil {
    // handle error
}

// Loop over items and unmarshal items.Inputs to Go type specific
// to each input type.    
for _, item := range data.Items {
    switch item.Type {
    case "type-of-item":
        var v struct{ Input1 string }
        if err := json.Unmarshal(item.Inputs, &v); err != nil {
            // handle error
        }
        fmt.Printf("%s has value %+v\n", item.Type, v)

    }
}
```

[Run it on the playground](https://play.golang.org/p/wNcDsRvDQon).

Answer (score 5):

In fairness Go would actually parse partially if you defined a partial struct. Quoting the documentation (https://blog.golang.org/json-and-go):

> How does Unmarshal identify the fields in which to store the decoded data? For a given JSON key "Foo", Unmarshal will look through the destination struct's fields to find (in order of preference):

```
An exported field with a tag of "Foo" (see the Go spec for more on struct tags),

An exported field named "Foo", or

An exported field named "FOO" or "FoO" or some other case-insensitive match of "Foo".
```

> What happens when the structure of the JSON data doesn't exactly match the Go type?

```
b := []byte(`{"Name":"Bob","Food":"Pickle"}`)
var m Message
err := json.Unmarshal(b, &m)
```

> Unmarshal will decode only the fields that it can find in the destination type. In this case, only the Name field of m will be populated, and the Food field will be ignored. This behavior is particularly useful when you wish to pick only a few specific fields out of a large JSON blob. It also means that any unexported fields in the destination struct will be unaffected by Unmarshal.

Answer (score 2):

Try gjson, super simple, you do not have to unmarshal the whole thing. you can take the bytes and pull a specific field out.
https://github.com/tidwall/gjson

```
    // Get string (has string, int, bool parsing)
    someField := gjson.ParseBytes(b).Get("some_field.some_nested_field").Str
    // Other types
    v, ok := gjson.ParseBytes(b).Get("some_other_field").Value().(map[string]string)
```